# How to convert System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem to list

Tags: c#

I want to display data using datatable so my hard coded System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem value and text collect and make a list using linq but get error System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,System.String]

var parentkeylist = clsDataCache.GetPriorityList().ToList();

```
  var parentkeylist = clsDataCache.GetPriorityList().ToList();//this is SelectListItem
```

List data = this.GetAllStpOrganizationEntityData(input);

```
            foreach (stp_organizationentityEntity obj in data)
            {
                    if (obj.parentkey != null)
                {
                    obj.priotytext = parentkeylist.Where(x => x.Value == obj.parentkey.ToString()).Select(x => x.Text).Cast<string>().ToString();//not cast Text value get error System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,System.String]  
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.priotytext = "Root";
                }
            }

            if (data != null && data.Count > 0)
            {
                long totalRecords = data.FirstOrDefault().RETURN_KEY;

                var tut = (from t in data
                           select new
                           {
                               t.entityname,
                               t.organizationkey,
                              t.priotytext,
                               t.entirytypekey,
                               t.entitylevel,
                               //t.seqfirstindex,
                               //t.seqfullindex,
                               // t.entitycpde,

                               //t.description,
                               t.isactive,
                               ex_nvarchar1 = objSecPanel.genButtonPanel(t.entitykey.GetValueOrDefault(-99), "entitykey", this.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity,
                               "StpOrganizationEntity/StpOrganizationEntityUpdate", "EditStpOrganizationEntity", "StpOrganizationEntity/StpOrganizationEntityDelete", "DeleteStpOrganizationEntity",
                               "StpOrganizationEntity/StpOrganizationEntityDetails", "StpOrganizationEntityDetails")
                           }).ToList();
```

}

var parentkeylist = clsDataCache.GetPriorityList().ToList();

```
  var parentkeylist = clsDataCache.GetPriorityList().ToList();//this is SelectListItem
```

List data = this.GetAllStpOrganizationEntityData(input);

```
            foreach (stp_organizationentityEntity obj in data)
            {
                    if (obj.parentkey != null)
                {
                    obj.priotytext = parentkeylist.Where(x => x.Value == obj.parentkey.ToString()).Select(x => x.Text).Cast<string>().ToString();//not cast Text value get error System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,System.String]  
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.priotytext = "Root";
                }
            }

            if (data != null && data.Count > 0)
            {
                long totalRecords = data.FirstOrDefault().RETURN_KEY;

                var tut = (from t in data
                           select new
                           {
                               t.entityname,
                               t.organizationkey,
                              t.priotytext,
                               t.entirytypekey,
                               t.entitylevel,
                               //t.seqfirstindex,
                               //t.seqfullindex,
                               // t.entitycpde,

                               //t.description,
                               t.isactive,
                               ex_nvarchar1 = objSecPanel.genButtonPanel(t.entitykey.GetValueOrDefault(-99), "entitykey", this.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity,
                               "StpOrganizationEntity/StpOrganizationEntityUpdate", "EditStpOrganizationEntity", "StpOrganizationEntity/StpOrganizationEntityDelete", "DeleteStpOrganizationEntity",
                               "StpOrganizationEntity/StpOrganizationEntityDetails", "StpOrganizationEntityDetails")
                           }).ToList();
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIvRk.png)

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem,System.String]

Comment: What type is x.Text?

Comment: `parentkeylist.Where(x => x.Value == obj.parentkey.ToString()).Select(x => x.Text).Cast<string>().ToString();` you are calling ToString() on an IEnumerable. If you wanted to get the string value from an IEnumerable<string> consider using String.Join.

Comment: x.Text  is SelectListItem Text  attribute and it was string

Comment: What @Kei said is true, The ".Select" does not return a single element from the list, but an IEnumerable. If you want to collect a single element use ".Single" or ". First" or ".First".

Comment: obj.priotytext = parentkeylist.Where(x => x.Value == obj.parentkey.ToString()).SingleOrDefault().Text; //after that get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Sounds like it could be one of three things: 1. parentkeylist is null, 2. obj.parentkey is null, or 3. there are no items in parentkeylist where x.Value == obj.parentkey

Comment: Always check for null when using SingleOrDefault()

Comment: Thanks Stefan i got my mistake base on your last comments